# how to bind the two different queries in a single repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I need to bind to data into a repeater based up on two different Queries. The Fields are different for the two queries. How to bind the both queries into single repeater?

Comment: Put a little more effort explaining this, please

Comment: can you explain more plz

Comment: Please re-read your own question. Did you use correct, understandable sentences? Did you explain your problem well? Then please edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your requirements. If you want to bind a nested repeater , then you can do it by binding the nested repeater in Item_Databound event to the query. If you want to bind the few controls in the same repeater to one query and few to another , then rethink what you are doing , may be you can do it with the one query.

It will be good if you explain your question in more details.
Thanks.